# Detect if the user arrived to the current page via the browser back button

Tags: javascript, navigation, cross-browser, back-button

I have a site where if a user navigates to a certain page then he gets a dialog notification depending on some condition on the page. The user can navigate to other pages from this page and of course can press the back button on those pages to navigate back to this page.

I'd like to detect if the user arrives via the back button to this page, so the dialog notification is not shown again (because the user has already seen it).

Is there a way to detect this reliably?

Answer (score 3):

[MDN list of window events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

Your best possibility may be `window.onpageshow = function(){};`

> An event handler property for pageshow events on the window.

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        alert("From back / forward cache.");
    }
};
```

Comment: Interesting. I checked the linked doc, but the persistent property and its behavior is not described there for some reason.

Comment: Found this, but the persisted property's description is pretty sparse: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pageshow

Comment: Yeah, I and it may or may not work on all browsers. Closest thing I could find though. There are a couple stackoverflow posts about it btw.

Comment: Works in 2023 with iOS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Input trick is not longer working. Here's the solution I use:

```
if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type === window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
    alert('Got here using the browser "Back" or "Forward" button.');
}
```

Comment: Its deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation

Answer (score 0):

The best (although not TREMENDOUSLY reliable) way is to use the Javascript history object. You can look at the history.previous page to see if it's the next in the series. Not a great solution, but maybe the only way to figure it out.

Comment: The other solution which occured to me is that I include the page request time in the page and show the dialog only if the running of the javascript code is within some threshold after page request, though it may also not be reliable, because page load time is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

I like use a value in an input field for this:-

```
<input type="hidden" id="fromHistory" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementById('fromHistory').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('fromHistory').value = 'fromHistory');
    alert('Arrived here normally');
} else {
    console.log('Arrived here from history, e.g. back or forward button');
}
</script>
```

This works because the browser repopulates the value of the field with the one the javascript puts in there if it navigates back to it from history :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's [window.performance navigationTiming](https://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/#example-3) API to detect whether the page is loaded by pressing back button.

```
if (window.performance) {
     var navEntries = window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation');
     if (navEntries.length > 0 && navEntries[0].type === 'back_forward') {
          console.log('this page is load from back/forward');
     } else {
          console.log('This is normal page load');
     }
} else {
     console.log("browser doesn't support this API");
}
```

There's a [deprecated api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation) as well to detect back button:

```
if (window.performance) {
     if (window.performance.navigation
      && window.performance.navigation.type == window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
          console.log('this page is load from back/forward');
     } else {
          console.log('This is normal page load');
     }
} else {
     console.log("browser doesn't support this API");
}
```

You can combine both to support oldest browsers.